# Arabic Language for R twitteR package functions

Tags: r, twitter, arabic

I have issues when using some twitteR functions when the language of tweet is Arabic, for example if I use twListToDF() and the tweet is in Arabic I get things like " ", I get the same with getTrends(). But when I make  SearchTwiter() I get normal Arabic characters, 
Kindly note that I use release 1.1.8.
Am I missing something with configuration or this is an issue with the package?

Comment: It might help if you post the code you are using.

Comment: Thank Tim,   this may happen with any simple code like this one:
> library(twitteR)
> lst.list<-searchTwitter(n=10,"#Oman")
> MyData.df=twListToDF(lst.list)###
> MyData.df  
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> and this is sample of the result
1RT : Six top plays to grace Original Theatre Festival in #Oman. http://t.co/LRSbMpOJz5 http://t.co/AVWp3FOz1x
2 RT : #<U+0627><U+064A><U+0631><U+0627>

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following command in the R, before using twListToDF()

Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "Arabic")

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while searching the internet regarding this same issue, and I found this package "arabicStemR". This might help.